# Existence of a Constant such that an integral inequality holds for all integrable functions

Tags: integration

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $f\colon U\rightarrow [0,1]$ be smooth with compact support in $U$. Let $p\ge 1$.
Does there exist a constant $C>0$ such that

$\int_U f^pg\ge C\int_Ufg$

for all integrable $g$ with $g\ge 0$?

If so, I would also be interested in how to prove that.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that $$\int_U (f^p-Cf)g\ge 0$$ for all integrable $g\ge 0$. This implies that $f^p\ge Cf$ almost everywhere. If $f$ is smooth with compact support, then this inequality can hold only for $p=1$.